# How to use ls command to show all the files including hidden files, but not showing the files named '.' and '..'

Tags: linux, bash, macos

The working directories contains several subdirectories, and each subdirectory contains some hidden files that start with `.`.

How could I use the `ls` command to display all the files including the hidden file, but I want to exclude the files name as `.` and `..`?

I tried `ls -a | grep -v '^\.'` but it does not show files in the subdirectories. And the option `-ignore` does not work, too.

Comment: A little bit confused by this question: How would `ls -a` show content in subdirectories? Is this a part of a larger script of some kind?

Answer (score 1):

If you want `ls` to show the sub-directories, you need to add the `-R`.

Your `grep -v '^\.'` will remove everything that starts with a `.`, so including the hidden files. A better pattern would be to explicitly remove just the `.` and `..` with `'^\.$|^\.\.$'`. The more specific you make the patterns, the less problems you have that unwanted lines are removed.

Putting that all together gives:

```
 ls -aR  | egrep -v '^\.$|^\.\.$'
```

Note that, if it is just the implied `.` and `..` that you want to remove, you can also use `ls -AR`. From `man ls`:

> ```
>   -a, --all
>          do not ignore entries starting with .
>
>   -A, --almost-all
>          do not list implied . and ..
> ```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. But is there any other way that not using the recursive option, cause the question also ask to not go through the third level subdirectories

Comment: I think, that instead of "how could I use the `ls` command" , you will want to use `find . -maxdepth 2`, possibly with `-type f` , so `find` instead of `ls`.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, `find` command is much more convenient, but this question explicitly says to us `ls` command;)

Answer (score 0):

Can’t test this right now, but fairly certain this will work. Wasn’t clear if you wanted to list the non-directory files in the working dir, so skipped my those.

```
ls -d */* */.??*
```